# How to let gnuplot find libgd?

Tags: shared-libraries, gnuplot

I encountered a problem exactly as [Terminal “png” missing when using Gnuplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22816030/terminal-png-missing-when-using-gnuplot)

The solution is to install libgd. However, the gnuplot is installed by administrator and I don't have administrator permission and even internet connection.

So I download the [libgd tar.gz](https://github.com/libgd/libgd/releases/tag/gd-2.2.4) and install it under my folder.

But the problem now is how to let gnuplot found my installed libgd?

Comment: You can't, you must build gnuplot completely from scratch.

Comment: @Christoph Ok, thank you for comment.